# Purpose of Last Print Statement

Tags: java, for-loop, nested

I can finally visualize nested for-loops, but I often see print statements such as "System.out.println();" at the end of a nested for-loop (usually a part of the outer loop).

I tried running a loop without that extra print statement, and it messed up not only the math of the Xs table, but also the formatting.

Could anyone give me an explanation on how to visualize the last print statement properly to create the neatly organized table?

Example:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
System.out.print(i + " | ");
for (int j = 1; j <= 9; j++) {
// Display the product and align properly
System.out.printf("%4d", i * j);
}
System.out.println(); // This is the print statement I'm referring to. How can I visualize this?
}
```

Comment: It prints a newline. If you remove it, everything will get printed on one line, which is probably not what you want for a table.

Comment: It ends the current line of output, so the next `print` statement will print at the beginning of the next line. Without that call, *all* the output would be on a single line (potentially wrapped in the console window, if it has a fixed width).

Answer (score 1):

This statement will execute after each 9 loops of j...

```
System.out.println(); // This is the print.....
```

put in your code like System.out.println("  ==> At i=" + i + " is over for j 9x-time..");
This way you will realize how this statement show on console or control flow of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println();
```

Creates a new line (ln) in your console. As you said the formatting get messed up when you delete this line of code because because you didn't get a new line after doing your first round in the outer loop of the nested for-loop.

In addition "\n" would do the same thing in a outprint statement without a linebreak.